# Question on magnetic levitation/thrust

Tags: design-alternative, advanced-propulsion

In the thoughts of using magnetics for space travel much like you could use magnets to levitate an item isn't their way to create a magnetic field that completely surrounds an object that propels outward cutting it to be able to be stationary in the air. And then to create smaller magnetic fields within that original magnetic field that would push against the inside of that magnetic field and of course great enough to cause the object Within to move in any given Direction I guess it would have to be in a way that it caused almost like how solar winds go around the planet and it makes a tail wherever the secondary magnetic force is pushing against the inside of the magnetic field it basically you'll be strong enough to put a rip in the magnetic field to where it opens in the shape of a tail I guess but where the ions would jet out in a Direction causing the object Within the original field to be thrust forward from that tail point I'm not really educated enough to explain it right but maybe you scientists whizzes can visualize what I'm talking about and explain it better but you can move the inner magnetic fields anywhere Within the surrounding magnetic field but at a higher magnitude then the field itself so it basically causes that magnetic field around the object to disperse the energy in any given Direction so the object in the center can be propelled in whatever Direction you want.

Please help me grow my potential and expand my mind

Comment: Welcome to SpaceSE. This is a question and answer site rather than a forum, so as starting point, can you please edit your question into the title, which I think is about magnetic levitation? Then edit the body to be a single question rather than a stream of conscience. If you cannot take the time to edit into a good question the probability of someone taking the time to write a good answer goes way down.

Comment: I have made some basic edits to your question to give it a question title and remove a number of tangents towards the end, you can revert them if you wish but would be better if you do a further edit to refine the core question, which is a think about making a magnetic field inside an existing one. Some links to things you have already read would also help (eg wikipedia magnetic levitation). Is now deleted, but worth being aware that one of the defining attributes of the dark matter is that it does not interact with magnetic fields.